# x raised to itself infinite number of times

Tags: exponentiation, power-towers

$$\Large x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{\,.^{\,.}}}}}}} = 2$$

What is $x$?

Comment: See this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/492109/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks for the link.  Apologies to anyone getting annoyed with dupes..it's quite hard searching for stuff here!

Comment: See [infinite tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have there is called an [infinite tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights). For your case, $x^2 = 2 \implies x = \sqrt2$.

In general, for $y = \Large x^{x^{x^{.^{\,.^{\,.}}}}}$, Euler showed that it is necessary that $e^{-e} \leq x \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ for convergence to occur for real $x$.

Comment: what if you tetrate something infinitly, (infinite pentration)?

Comment: Yiyuan, This is the answer I needed. However if the RHS is 4, then the solution would be 4^(1/4) which is exactly √2 .  Thus it seems that the same sequence of numbers has not one limit (2), but two limits: 2 and 4. Could you, please, explain this paradox?
 .

Comment: Yiyuan, I found the answer here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05559.pdf . the value of the RHS must be in the interval:
`[1/e, e]`.  This means that only two natural numbers  qualify as values of the RHS: 1 and 2.

Comment: I edited the answer, adding this new information - hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 5):

So, we have $$x^2=2$$

In general, if $$x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}=y, x^y=y$$

Comment: This is a good answer if you have convergence.  Convergence needs to be demonstrated to make this work.

Comment: @RossMillikan, if the Right Hand Side is finite, so should be the left, right?

Comment: It takes more than that.  Think of $1-1+1-1\dots$  A similar argument would be $S=1-1+1-1\dots=1-S, S=\frac 12$ but I can make it come out other things.

Comment: Except that here every element of the sequence is identical.