# Why is $x=4$ as a fixed point of a map $\sqrt{2}^{x}$ unstable?

Tags: dynamical-systems, exponentiation, fixed-point-theorems, power-towers

My question is motivated by this [What is wrong with this funny proof that 2 = 4 using infinite exponentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492109/what-is-wrong-with-this-funny-proof-that-2-4-using-infinite-exponentiation?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussion, namely an example of a map $x \mapsto f(x)$ is given, with $$f(x)= (\sqrt{2})^{x}.$$ In that thread, it is stated the map has 2 fixed points, at $x = 2$ and $x=4$. Now to examine their stability we look at the derivative $$f'(x) = (\sqrt{2})^{x} \log \sqrt{2}.$$

Now we have $f'(4) <1$, so $x=4$ should be stable. However, it is claimed, on the contrary, that $x=4$ is, in fact, $\textbf{unstable}$. Why is this?

Comment: Around $x=4$? The derivative is $2 \log 2$, or roughly $1.4$.

Comment: My apologies! Was doing computations in terms of logs to base 10, rather than natural logarithms. May close the thread. @PatrickStevens

Comment: I'd like to have the question closed/deleted because it's on a false premise. For the case this is not wanted I added a formal answer which is "acceptable" for closing the case.

Answer (score 1):

The question was based on a false premise and is superflous now (see comments below question) as based on a simple error as understood by the OP.